# postgres find all databases who has owner 'abc'?

Tags: python, postgresql, shell, ubuntu

in postgresql i wanted to find all databases who has owner 'abc' and then change all databases owner to 'xyz'. I tried to change owner but it only igives gor one database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run

```
select 'ALTER DATABASE '||datname||' OWNER TO "xyz";'
from pg_database
where datdba = 'abc'::regrole;
```

then capture its output, and run it.